# Why is a pointwise limit of a measurable function measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading the proof on Royden, but could not convince myself of the following line. The Union and intersections do not quite make sense to me. Can anyone give me some intuition and help me understand the following equation?

$$ \{ x \in E \mid f(x) < c\} =\bigcup\limits_{1<=k,n<\infty} \bigcap\limits_{j=k}^{\infty}  \left\{ x \in E \mid  f_j(x) < c  - \frac{1}{n}  \right\} $$

Comment: Union and intersection over what?

Comment: What section of the book is this from?

Comment: Was pulled into an urgent meeting while editing the formula. Just finished editing. It is from page 61 of Royden real analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presuming what we have here is a sequence of functions $f_i$ on $E$ that converge pointwise to a function $f$. The right side should be
$$ \bigcup_{n =1}^\infty\; \bigcup_{M =1}^\infty\; \bigcap_{i = M}^\infty \{x \in E \mid f_i(x) < c - 1/n \}$$

1. Suppose $f(x) < c$.  Then there is some $n$ such that $f(x) < c - 2/n$.
   Moreover, there is some $M$ such that for all $i \ge M$, $|f_i(x) - f(x)| < 1/n$.  These imply that $f_i(x) \le f(x) + |f_i(x) - f(x)| < c - 1/n$.  This says $x$ is in the set on the right.
2. Conversely, suppose $x$ is in the set on the right.  That says that there exist $n$ and $M$ such that for all $i \ge M$, $f_i(x) < c - 1/n$.  Since 
   $f(x) = \lim_{i \to \infty} f_i(x)$, we have $f(x) \le c - 1/n$, and so $f(x) < c$.

Comment: I was  reading through the proof again, but cannot make sense of the infinite unions and intersections. What is a good way to make sense of it?

Comment: $x \in \bigcap_{n} A_n$ means $x$ is in $A_n$ for all $n$.  $x \in \bigcup_n A_n$ means $x$ is in $A_n$ for some $n$.  So an expression involving $\bigcup$ and $\bigcap$ translates to a condition involving quantifiers "for all" and "for some".

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to follow (what are the union and intersection over?), so here's an alternative.

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions. We now show that $g=\sup f_n$ is measurable. Let $a$ be arbitrary. We need to show that $g^{-1}(a,\infty]$ is measurable. If $x$ is in $X$ (the underlying space), $g(x) > a$ if and only if $f_n(x)>a$ for some $n$. Therefore, $$g^{-1}(a,\infty]=\bigcup_n f_n^{-1}(a,\infty],$$ and the desired result follows.

It follows that $\inf f_n = -\sup\{-f_n\}$ is measurable too. In fact, so is $\limsup f_n$ since $$\limsup f_n=\inf_{n\geq 1}\sup_{k \geq n} f_k.$$

Therefore, when the limit exists, it is equal to $\lim f_n = \limsup f_n$, and the desired result follows.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Just updated the formula.